# Salesforce Triggered Send - Secondary Email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I have a secondary email address field (Custom Field) on Leads and I need to send a Triggered Email to this custom Field.

While creating a Triggered Send in Salesforce, the Recepient Lookup field doesn't allow me to select anything other than the Lead ID. Is there a way to send email to a field that is not the primary email field.

Comment: Any ideas for this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating a Triggered Send Definition in Marketing Cloud and using the Marketing Cloud API.

The API will let you specify the From Email address and you can reference any field there. Sample REST API request JSON is mentioned below.

> Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com POST
>   /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:cust_key/send Content-Type:
>   application/json Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> ```
> {
>     "From": {
>         "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
>         "Name": "Code@"
>     },
>     "To": {
>         "Address": "example@example.com",
>         "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
>         "ContactAttributes": {
>             "SubscriberAttributes": {
>                 "Region": "West",
>                 "City": "Indianapolis",
>                 "State": "IN"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     "OPTIONS": {
>         "RequestType": "ASYNC"
>     }
> }
> ```